# Direct3D texture resource life cycle

Tags: windows-phone-8, direct3d

I have been working on a project with Direct3D on Windows Phone. It is just a simple game with 2d graphics, and I make use of DirectXTK for helping me out with sprites.

Recently , I have come across to an out of memory error while I was debugging on 512mb emulator. This error was not common and was the result of a sequence of open, suspend , open , suspend ...

Tracking it down, I found out that the textures are loaded on every activation of the app, and finally filling up the allowed memory. To solve it , I will probably go and edit it so as to load textures only on opening but activation from suspends; but after this problem I am curious about the correct life cycle management of texture resources. While searching I have came across to Automatic (or "managed" by microsoft) Texture Management [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172341(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .  which can probably help out with some management of the textures in video memory.

However, I also would like to know other methods since I couldnt figure out a good way to incorporate managed textures into my code.

My best is to call the Release method of ID3D11ShaderResourceView pointers I store in destructors to prevent filling up the memory , but how do I ensure textures are resting in memory while other apps would want to use it(the memory)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows phone uses Direct3D 11 which 'virtualizes' the GPU memory. Essentially every texture is 'managed'. If you want a detailed description of this, see "[Why Your Windows Game Won't Run In 2,147,352,576 Bytes?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/16/windows-x64.aspx). The link you provided is Direct3D 9 era for Windows XP XPDM, not any Direct3D 11 capable platform.

It sounds like the key problem is that your application is leaking resources or has too large a working set. You should enable the [debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) and first make sure you have cleaned up everything as you expected. You may also want to check that you are following the recommendations for launching/resuming on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207014%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Also keep in mind that Direct3D 11 uses 'deferred destruction' of resources so just because you've called Release everywhere doesn't mean that all the resources are actually gone... To force a full destruction, you need to use [Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

With Windows phone 8.1 and Direct3D 11.2, there is a specific Trim functionality you can use to reduce an app's memory footprint, but I don't think that's actually your issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. While I as trying to figure out the issue and searching for automatic texture management, that link was where i ended up and assumed the same principles would apply, my bad. Actually, for my problem after I started using Release when necessary, my problem is solved.

Comment: But the thing is, I have to load and release textures every time app is activated (new launch or background) which is ok for my humble game.But I thought more heavy games wouldnt do that considering texture loading can take some time. And some heavy games I played could come foreground instantly. Sorry if I couldnt make it clear in post, but I wanted know how textures are managed more smartly. I mean,when app is opened textures are loaded, when app goes background and comes to foreground again I may not have to reload the textures(maybe still in memory). virtualization my be the answer here?